# Put it on, get higher

Tags: riddle

> Put it on, get higher,
>
> Put it down, what a shame,
>
> Lose it at the end
>
> And have no one to blame

What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it

> Our head?

Put it on, get higher,

> We lift our head up, and get higher in pride.

Put it down, what a shame,

> Head is down in shame

Lose it at the end

> Death is the end

And have no one to blame

> Natural death

Comment: I'll probably accept that, was thinking of honor, or pride, but by your statements, it's identical